# Should this Task.Run in a loop, leak memory?

Tags: c#, multithreading, task, threadpool

Given this simple C# code:-

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    while (true)
    {
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            Thread.Sleep(50);
        });

        Thread.Sleep(40);
    }
}
```

Should this leak memory?

My understanding is that these tasks will be queued on the thread pool and executed concurrently, meaning that (aside from delays etc in handling) at most two threads would be used.

I.e.:-

- The first iteration creates a task that takes 50ms and let's say this
  runs on "Thread 1".
- The second iteration 40ms later creates another task. "Thread 1" is busy, so this task is run on "Thread 2".
- The third iteration, another 40ms later (and now 80ms since the first iteration) creates another task. By this stage, the first task on "Thread 1" is complete, so "Thread 1" can be used.
- And so on.

## EDIT

Diagram

[image]

## EDIT 2

Whilst the question is focused on how this *should* work and not how it does work, the results are that on Windows/.NET, memory usage remains static over time, whereas with Linux/Mono, memory usage increases.

Watching ThreadPool counts also support the idea that multiple threads are used to complete tasks concurrently.

Comment: It's an inefficient memory use, but not a leak.

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: @zerkms thanks. I understand it's not practical code; this is more a thought exercise to confirm that memory usage should remain stable, and not increase over time.

Comment: @DourHighArch on Windows/.net CLR, memory usage is static. On Linux/Mono, memory usage increases over time.

Comment: @Aleks how is it possible to memory would remain the same given you allocate more tasks than you may run?

Comment: @zerkms, per the latter part of the question, I'm currently expecting (and hence me asking the question to see if my thinking is wrong), that because these are not being executed consecutively, that threads in the pool will expand to run the tasks, and ask those tasks complete, the threads become available again. At some point (depending the ratio between loop delay and task length) this should settle into a static number of threads. And as each task completes, GC will collect any resources used by that task.

Comment: So it sounds like you tested it already on Windows where memory usage was static but on Linux+Mono memory increased?  If so, it may be a bug with Mono.  Mono isn’t .NET.   By the way you might want to include these platform test results in your question as it is very useful I feel

Comment: @MickyD that is correct, however, I've tried to deliberately steer away from the actual results, as I'm trying to get clarification around my thinking of how it should work, not how it does. I understand the difference between Mono and .NET, which is why I only tagged as C#, which is applicable to both. I have already raised a ticket with Mono, however, it was dismissed out of hand and I'm now reviewing if my understanding of the mechanism is correct.

Comment: @zerkms makes a good point that memory shouldn’t remain static because you are `queuing task creation faster than they complete`.   I don’t know enough to know if the CLR will start to discard things under heavy load

Comment: @MickyD I added a diagram to try to clarify why I think they shouldn't stack up

Comment: @mjwills per my earlier comments, I'm trying to avoid implementation details, and get a clear answer on the theory, hence the specific tags chosen. I'm not trying to solve the memory leak here; only to understand if it's reasonable that memory does leak, irrespecitve of the implementaion, be it .NET, Mono, .NET Core

Comment: Well, as the other comments mentioned, this shouldn't leak. As to why you're seeing a leaking behavior on Mono, it could simply be that the GC is tuned differently. If you try on .net framework/.net core with ServerGC activated, you'll see the same kind of "leak-like" behavior. If you want to be sure, call `GC.Collect` once in a while. If the memory keeps increasing despite that then indeed you've found a leak

Comment: Thanks @KevinGosse, that is a good point on GC. In my testing, I had just allowed GC to "do it's thing". The results I have so far are a linear increase in memory over 24 hours where I had just assumed GC would have kicked in. I will do more testing with some explicit collection to see the impact. It is good to get confirmation that, provided GC has collected, the above should not continue to consume memory.